# Estimating the shift in the $\lambda_{\max}$ of a matrix under a diagonal perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory

Given a matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $D$, how can we estimate $\lambda_{\max}(A+D) - \lambda_{\max}(A)$? Feel free to make other assumptions about the matrices that they are all symmetric and have entries in $1,-1,0$.

---

I see some related questions, e.g.,

- [Spectral radius of a rank-1 perturbation](https://mathoverflow.net/q/209778)
- [Relation between the subordinate norm and the spectral radius of a matrix](https://mathoverflow.net/q/177872)
- [The spectral radius of a modified graph](https://mathoverflow.net/q/158930)
- [Eigenvectors as continuous functions of matrix - diagonal perturbations](https://mathoverflow.net/q/207452)

Comment: What is the motivation for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Because $A \mapsto \|A\|_{op} := \sup_{x\ne0} \frac{\|Ax\|_2}{\|x\|_2}$ defines a *matrix norm*, we have the triangle inequality $\|A + D\|_{op} \le \|A\|_{op} + \|D\|_{op}$, i.e
\begin{eqnarray}
\|A + D\|_{op} - \|A\|_{op} \le \|D\|_{op} = \sup_{1\le i\le n} |d_i|.
\end{eqnarray}

Further because the spectral radius $r(A) := \sup\{|\lambda| \mid \lambda \in \operatorname{spec}(A)\}$ is upper-bounded by $\|A\|_{op}$ (exercise), we have
\begin{eqnarray}
r(A+D) - \|A\|_{op} \le \sup_{1 \le i \le n}|d_i|.
\end{eqnarray}

I don't think you can get anything tighter without further assumptions.

Comment: Can you kindly explain how you dissolved $\vert \vert A + D \vert \vert_2$ ?

Comment: $\|A\|_2$ is not the right quantity to look at. Just consider the case $\lambda_{\max}(A)\leq0$ (i.e., $A\leq0$) in which $\|A\|_2=-\lambda_{\min}(A)$ is as far off from $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ as possible. Besides, $r(A)=\|A\|_2$ for a symmetric matrix $A$.

Comment: Instead of writing `\underset{1\le i\le n} {\text{sup }}`, you should write `\sup_{1\le i\le n}` I edited accordingly. In a "displayed", as opposed to inline, setting, that results in $\displaystyle\sup_{1\le i\le n},$ with the subscript directly below $\sup,$ and in an inline setting it results in $\sup_{1\le i\le n}.$ The horizontal spacing before and after `\sup` depends on the context---the software takes care of that. Not so with `\text{}`. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

You need $A$, $D$ symmetric to guarantee that the eigenvalues are real. Then you have the elementary estimate
\begin{multline*}
\max\{\lambda_{\max}(A)+\lambda_{\min}(D),\lambda_{\min}(A)+\lambda_{\max}(D)\} \\ \leq \lambda_{\max}(A+D) \leq \lambda_{\max}(A)+\lambda_{\max}(D),
\end{multline*}
and this estimate is sharp as easy examples with $A$ being diagonal show.

EDIT: For instance,
\begin{multline*}
\lambda_{\max}(A+D) = \max_{\|x\|_2=1}\langle (A+D)x,x\rangle \\ \geq
\max_{\|x\|_2=1}\langle Ax,x\rangle + \min_{\|x\|_2=1}\langle
Dx,x\rangle =\lambda_{\max}(A) + \lambda_{\min}(D).
\end{multline*}

Comment: This is a good answer. You have my upvote. But you should add a reference to Weyl inequalities (which are far from elementary, given the state of affairs...) or other combo. Statements like "this or that is elementary" are not very useful to the user.

Comment: @dohmatob This particular case of the Weyl inequalities is indeed straightforward. I've made an edit to my answer.